# DataGridView control unresponsive during update from BackgroundWorker

Tags: winforms, datagridview, backgroundworker

I have a Windows Forms application with a DataGridView control which is updated a few times a second from a routine called by BackgroundWorker_DoWork. In this condition, no scroll bars are visible on the control and  the control is unresponsive to clicks. If the updating is stopped, scroll bars are visible and the control is responsive.

Is there a way of making the DataGridView responsive when it being updated via Backgroundworker?

Comment: [Show Loading animation during loading data in other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39140469/3110834)

Comment: What's Loading animation?

Comment: Read the linked answer, the answer contains enough information showing you how to load data asynchronously and show a 'loading ...' image.