# Show animated gif on user control initialization

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, gif

I have a `UserControl`, which I use to send a HTTP request to an API. The code for sending, is located in the `ViewModel`, but it is invoked on by the UserControl, currently using the `Load` event. While awaiting completion of the HTTP request, I would like to show an animated gif.

The problem is this: I can succesfully show the gif, using the load event and make it go away, once the HTTP request is complete. But the animation does not work. This is not a problem with the gif itself, since it works fine in all other usage. The problem seem to be connected to the fact, that the code is invoked from the `Load` event (instead of a button click for example).

Can I add some code, to make the gif animate properly? Or is there a better event to use, than `Load`?

**Update**

I did manage to change the code, so the animation starts. But quite quickly it freezes again. I did so using `picLoading.Show()` and `picLoading.Update()`, instead of the whole `Visible` thing.

**Load event (in user control)**

```
private async void MyUserControl_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Display the loading animated gif
    picLoading.Visible = true;

    // Wait for the http request to complete 
    await viewModel.HttpRequestMethod(host, path);

    // Once completed, hide the picture again
    picLoading.Visible = false;
}
```

**HTTP request method (in view model)**

```
public async Task<string> HttpRequestMethod(string host, string path)
{
    HttpClient httpClient;
    CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler()
    {
        CookieContainer = cookieContainer,
        UseDefaultCredentials = true
    };

    httpClient = new HttpClient(handler)
    {
        BaseAddress = new Uri(host)
    };

    HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = httpClient.GetAsync(path).Result;

    httpResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    return await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

Comment: Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39142535/3110834).

Comment: @RezaAghaei I have actually managed to make something like that, work. With a `Button_Click` event, that is. But when I use the `Load` event, then my gif refuse to animate correctly.

Comment: Using the Load event is pretty dangerous, it can fire very early and the UI thread might not have been initialized sufficiently yet to allow async/await to work correctly.  It doesn't do what it is supposed to do until Application.Run() is called.  Set breakpoints.  Consider that it needs help to decide when to run, add a public method and call it in the form's Shown event.

Comment: @HansPassant I cannot see any `Shown` event. The event is occurring in a user control, inside a form.

Comment: That's why I recommended to add a public method to your usercontrol.  So the *form's* Shown event can help you get the download started.

Comment: @HansPassant it's a bit more complicated, unfortunately. The user control is not shown until quite a bit later (based on user input). But I appreciate you input, and it is nice that you could confirm my suspicion regarding the `Load` event.

Comment: @Noceo Load event of a `Control` is not a suitable place for showing such Loading window.