# C# WinForms Help in Implementing BackgroundWorker and Loading Form

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2017

**What i want to achieve :**

- Step 1: When the form loads, I wanted to display a Loading Form (as dialog) which contains a Progress Bar and a Progress Label.
- Step 2: While this is happening, I want to run a `BackgroundWorker` to retrieve the records from a database and fill my `DataTable`. The `BackgroundWorker` will update the Loading Form of the stages it has completed.
- Step 3: When all records has been retrieved, close the Loading Form and display the records in the `DataGridView`

**Things to note :**

- The `DataGridView` is bound to my `DataSet.[Table]`.
- The Loading Form is a Windows Form not a `MessageBox`.
- I'm using Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition.
- I plan to use this implementation for all my database interactions such as Update Etc.

**Issues :**

- How can update the Progress Bar & Progress Label control on the Loading Form from `bgwTransactionListing_ProgressChange`
- My `bgwTransactionListing_DoWork` is really not doing any work.

**Code**

Here is the code for `Form_Load`

```
namespace MyApplication
{
     public partial class frmTransactionListing : Form
     {
          public frmTransactionListing()
          {
              InitializeComponent();
          }

          frmload LoadingForm = new frmload();

          private void frmTransactionListing_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
          {
              bgwTransactionListing.RunWorkerAsync();
          }
```

Here is my code for `BacgroundWorker_DoWork`:

```
private void bgwTransactionListing_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            bgwTransactionListing.ReportProgress(0, "Loading Records");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
            bgwTransactionListing.ReportProgress(100, "Completed");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("We have encountered an error and cannot proceed. Error: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Here is my code for `BacgroundWorker_ProgressChanged`:

```
private void bgwTransactionListing_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {            
        if(e.ProgressPercentage == 0)
        {
            LoadingForm.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
```

Here is my code for `BackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted`. This is where I am trying to close the Loading Form:

```
private void bgwTransactionListing_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        dgTransactionList.Refresh();
    }
```

Advanced Thanks to all your help.

> UPDATE 1: I disabled the loading form and tried putting the Table
>   Adapter Fill method on `RunWorkerCompleted` and the `DataGridView` is
>   now displaying the records. I thought the Fill Method is the process
>   of retrieving records from my database. Apparently its not.
>
> UPDATE 2: I have updated the codes with what I currently have after i applied
>   the suggestions from @russelrillema @Jimi. Now, I am able to show and close the
>   Loading From. I have also updated my issues.

Comment: Not the cleanest approach but if this is the route you are going can you not store the frmload globally. Initialise it in the frmTransactionListing_Load and then you'll have access to it in the bgwTransactionListing_RunWorkerCompleted where you can close it?

Comment: I stored it globally because im planning to use it for all my other database interactions.

Comment: Based on your samples LoadingForm is being created in frmTransactionListing_Load so it's not currently global.
What I mean is put frmload LoadingForm; outside of frmTransactionListing_Load and then inside the frmTransactionListing_Load method put LoadingForm = new frmload();
Then you will have access to LoadingForm inside all methods in the frmTransactionListing class

Comment: After `LoadingForm.ShowDialog();`, the code stops there. It will continue with `bgwTransactionListing.RunWorkerAsync();` only after you have closed `LoadingForm`.

Comment: Thank you @russelrillema for your inputs. I will try your suggestions.

Comment: Thank you @Jimi for your inputs. I will try your suggestions.

Comment: I didn't actually suggest anything. I'm saying that you can't show a modal Form *and* excute the code that comes after at the same time. The current code will not continue until the modal Form is closed. You could opt for a progress animation, [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39142535/7444103), since you're fill a `TableAdapter`, which doesn't provide means to show a `ProgressBar`. Or simply show the standard waiting cursor. I wouldn't waste too much time implementing something like this. Maybe when you upgrade/update the application (unless you're already there :).

Comment: Or you could show the second Form using just  `LoadingForm.Show(this);`.

Comment: I have a sample for a WPF app [here](https://github.com/SirRufo/WpfWithSplash/blob/master/WpfWithSplash/App.xaml.cs) - you may find it useful