# Show a text in DataGridView when it is empty

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

How can I show a text in the grey part of a `DataGridView` when it's empty.

I found this example but not work in VB.net

```
GridView1.EmptyDataText="No Records Found";
```

Comment: `EmptyDataText` is a property for  Web Forms `GridView` control. For Windows Forms, you need to render the text yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`EmptyDataText` is a property of Web Forms `GridView` control. In Windows Forms, to show a text when `DataGridView` doesn't have any row, you need to render the text yourself. To do so, you can handle `Paint` event of `DataGridView` and render the text using `TextRenderer.DrawText`.

**C#**

```
private void dataGridView1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count == 0)
        TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, "No records found.",
            dataGridView1.Font, dataGridView1.ClientRectangle,
            dataGridView1.ForeColor, dataGridView1.BackgroundColor,
            TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter | TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter);
}
```

**VB.NET**

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) _
    Handles DataGridView1.Paint
    If DataGridView1.Rows.Count = 0 Then
        TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, "No records found.",
            DataGridView1.Font, DataGridView1.ClientRectangle,
            DataGridView1.ForeColor, DataGridView1.BackgroundColor,
            TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter Or TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: In what method could I paint the text "loading data" while executing my query in the background?

Comment: To show loading, I'd suggest using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39142535/3110834).

Comment: Thanks. I have resolved the problem using the example posted above. What I did was to use an event that indicates when the data load in background has finished. Then, using a flag I managed the text showing in the textRenderer. While the background worker is running I show the text "loading data". Once the background worked has finished I show the data or in the case that the datagridView.rows.cout =0 the text "No records found"

Comment: Yes you can do it as well. However the linked post is also a good example of showing a loading animation + using async/await pattern to load data.